# How to open one GNU screen tab for each directory in a list

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, bash-scripting

I have the following script - it *sort of* works.

```
#!/bin/bash  

... define plugins, etc

for plugin in ${plugins[@]};
do 
  screen -t $plugin
done
```

**Want I want it to do**

open gnu-screen and for each plugin (which is a directory name), start a new tab with the plugin's name as the tab's title.

**What it does now**

opens gnu-screen and opens the first plugin in an instance of screen (with the correct title) but doesn't keep running through commands.  so when I exit the first screen, the second plugin is opened in an instance of screen, when I exit that, the third is open, etc..

**What I'm missing**

I'd like to just say `screen -t $plugin &&`, as in, run this thing and then run the next. but I'm not sure how to do that in a for loop

Comment: You can start screen detached using `-d -m` but that doesn't seem to allow to add windows to existing sessions. `tmux` does support this using the `new-window` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

plugins=(Plugin1 Plugin2 Plugin3)

plugin_cmd="#!/bin/bash\necho This is plugin __placeholder__\n"
for plugin in ${plugins[@]};
do
    echo -e ${plugin_cmd/__placeholder__/$plugin} > /tmp/${plugin}.bash
    chmod +x /tmp/${plugin}.bash
    screen -dmS $plugin
    screen -S $plugin -X stuff "/tmp/${plugin}.bash\n"
    screen -d -r -S $plugin
done
```

Take Thom Wigger's advice and switch to tmux.

Comment: had to switch to tmux, but this worked a treat. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate a custom .screenrc?

E.g. if your folder with plugins does not change often then write this to a file.

```
# Setting custom things:
startup_message off   

# starting a few shells with a preselected title
screen -t plugin1 0
screen -t plugin2 1
screen -t plugin3 2
screen -t my_email  -a -l exec elm
```

---

If the number of plugin changes frequently then you could use your bash script to write them to a file. E.g.

```
rm ~/my_custom_screenrc
echo "# Setting custom things:" > ~/my_custom_screenrc
echo "startup_message off"      >> ~/my_custom_screenrc
```

Followed by your bash script where you change the

```
for plugin in ${plugins[@]};
do 
  screen -t $plugin
done
```

with an echo to append (`>>`) to the same file as above.

Finally start screen. E.g. `screen -c ~/my_custom_screenrc`

---

This is far from a perfect answer and I expect to so *proper* answers within the week. But I saw no way to post this as a comment and still keep sufficient markup to keep it understandable.

Comment: I'm starting to think this may be the winner ;)

Comment: The nw post from John Schmitt seems a good one. Also +1 on Tmux. (Or rather -1000 from people who looked at the source code for screen).

Comment: +1 anyway, i think your solution is not a bad one.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
screen -t $plugin xterm &
```

instead of your version. *screen* opens a new shell, inside which you will be trapped, without any possibility to continue the *do* loop; thus the ampersand makes sure that control is immediately returned to the *do* loop, while *xterm* (or konsole, or whatever you like) gives a place, so to speak, where screen is doing its job.

Comment: in the case of four plugins, changing the script as you suggest prints 'Must be connected to a terminal.' four times and exits.

Comment: Tried this on a Debian Wheezy using Screen 4.01.00devel as of 05/02/06 and it worked. Could you please give some more information: are you already running `screen`? Do you start your script remotely via `ssh` or detached as a `cron` job?  What OS is running below?

Comment: Are you talking to me? If so: I use Arch Linux/Debian Jessie/Kubuntu, I start the script both as a systemd boot script and via ssh. I can have screen already running or not. On Kubuntu (system I am writing from) I have screen 4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9

Comment: @ua2b as for me - i'm on Arch 3.17.2 using screen 4.3.30(1).  Screen is not running, I'm starting the script 'normally' from the command line - not remotely via ssh or detached.  I'm using gnome-terminal.